# How To Manage Guard.Against.NotFound for IAggregateRoot

Tags: domain-driven-design, .net-5, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I was wondering if we want to check for adding new item if projectId exist in db, shell we somehow in `AddItem` method to insert `Guard.Agains.NotFound(???)` or not?
I'm asking because if create some entity:

```
public class Country : BaseEntity<int>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<District> _districts = new List<District>();
    public IEnumerable<District> Districts => _districts.AsReadOnly();

    public Country(string name)
    {
        Name = Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(name, nameof(name));
    }

    public void AddDistrict(District newDistrict)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(newDistrict, nameof(newDistrict));
        Guard.Against.NegativeOrZero(newDistrict.CountryId, nameof(newDistrict.CountryId));

        _districts.Add(newDistrict);
    }
}


public class District : BaseEntity<int>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<Municipality> Municipalities { get; set; }

}
```

How we can validate if countryId sent by request exist in DB ?
Example if create integration test like :

```
[Fact]
public async Task AddDistrict()
{
        var districtName = "District";
        var countryRepository = GetCountryRepository();

        var country = new Country("Country");
        await countryRepository.AddAsync(country);
        var district = new District
        {
            CountryId = 2,
            Name = districtName
        };
        country.AddDistrict(district);

        await countryRepository.UpdateAsync(country);

        Assert.Equal(1, district.Id);

}
```

No matter with intenger value I put as CountryId test will pass till is not 0 or negative integer, but I want to check if that id of country entity exist in DB. Where would be best place to manage this check ?
Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to request a Country object be provided to the constructor of District:

```
public class District
{
   public string Name { get; private set; }
   public int CountryId { get; private set; }

   public District(string name, Country country)
   {
       if (country == null)
           throw new Exception("Missing country.");

       Name = name;

       CountryId = country.Id
   }
}
```

Now you've force the client of the domain to provide a Country.  If the client (application layer) cannot retrieve a valid Country from the Country repository based on the provided id then your constructur will throw upon getting a null country.

---

Alternatively, keep the CountryId as a constructor parameter on District, make the District constructor internal so that it cannot be created outside of the domain and then make the Country object the factory for District:

```
public class Country
{
    public District CreateDistrict(string name)
    {
        return new District(name, this.Id);
    }
}
```

This will also force client to get a concrete Country before asking it to create the District.

Comment: These are all good options!